# Minify css from webpack's ExtractTextPlugin and style-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

In this tracer repo: https://github.com/pconerly/libsass-spritesmith-webpack-tracer

And this line:
https://github.com/pconerly/libsass-spritesmith-webpack-tracer/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L82

I'm loading `.scss`, and extracting them into plaintext. I'd also like to minify them--- how do I do that? `style-loader` doesn't seem to have an option for it.  Should I be using another plugin like `css-loader` instead?

Answer (score 14):

So this will come automatically through the CSS loader unless you've explicitly disabled it. Since you're asking the question I'm assuming this means you have. The `UglifyJsPlugin` won't minify the CSS by itself if you're extracting and not minifying.

For my needs I needed to extract the CSS and then provide both a minified and non-minified version. So I ran into the same problem where I could have it minified or non-minified but not both.

I was able to get this to work using the [optimize-css-assets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin) plugin for Webpack. It will allow you to minify the CSS you've extracted using `ExtractTextPlugin` and you can set a RegEx rule similar to the `UglifyJsPlugin` settings.

By default this plugin uses the `css-nano` module for it's compression, although you can swap out to your preferred module if you wish.

Here's a basic configuration:

```
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: { warnings: false },
    include: /\.min\.js$/
  }),
  new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
    assetNameRegExp: /\.min\.css$/,
    cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }
  })
]
```

Comment: @Civilian do you mind if you could make this answer correct?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking at postcss and postcss-loader. That way once you have it set up you can do lots of cool stuff to you CSS/SCSS without having to spend days fighting webpack first.

Answer (score -5):

Adding an entry for the `UglifyJsPlugin` works for me.

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compressor: { warnings: false }
    })
]
```

Comment: The UglifyJsPlugin only compresses javascript. The question was about compressing css.